# .NET Regex - get parts of string that do not match pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string

```
TEST_TEXT_ONE_20112017
```

I want to eliminate _20112017, which is a underscore with numbers, those numbers can vary; my goal is to have only

```
TEST_TEXT_ONE
```

So far I have this but I get the entire string, is there something I'm missing?

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b\w+[0-9]+\b");
MatchCollection words = r.Matches("TEST_TEXT_ONE_20112017");

foreach(Match word in words)
{
   string w = word.Groups[0].Value;
   //I still get the entire string
}
```

Comment: you can use `Replace` instead to replace the match with something else or in your case remove matches by replacing with an empty string.

Comment: You dont need Regex for this at all

Comment: does `TEST_TEXT_ONE` also change?

Comment: @LuisColorado yes

Comment: so what is the format of the whole thing? not explaining things or doing partially will not help you.

Answer (score 3):

Notes for your consideration:

1. You should use parenthesis to mark groups for capture -or- use named group. The first group (index=0) is the entire match. you probably want index=1 instead.
2. `\w` stands for [word character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WordCharacter) and it already includes both underscore and digits. If you want to match anything before the numbers then you should consider using `.` instead of `\w`.
3. by default `+`is greedy and your `\w+` will consume your last undescore and all but the very last number as well. You probably want to explicitly require an underscore before last block of numbers.
4. I would suggest considering if you want to find a matching substring or the entire string to match. if the latter, then consider using the start and end markers: `^` and `$`.
5. if you know you want to eliminate 8 digits, then you could giving explicit count like `\d{8}`

For example this should work:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^(.+)_\d+$");
MatchCollection words = r.Matches("TEST_TEXT_ONE_20112017");
foreach (Match word in words)
{
    string w = word.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

**Alternative**

Use a [Zero-Width Positive Lookahead Assertions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) construct to check what comes next without capturing it. This uses the syntax on `(?=stuff)`. So you could use a shorter code and avoid surfing in Groups altogether:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^.+(?=_\d+$)");
String result = r.Match("TEST_TEXT_ONE_20112017").Value;
```

Note that we require the end marker `$` within the positive lookahead group.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\b.+)_([0-9]+)\b");
String w = r.Match("TEST_TEXT_ONE_20112017").Groups[1].Value; //TEST_TEXT_ONE
```

or:

```
String w = r.Match("TEST_TEXT_ONE_20112017").Groups[2].Value; //20112017
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit overkill for Regex in my opinion. As an alternative you could just split on the `_` character and rebuild the string:

```
private static string RemoveDate(string input)
{
    string[] parts = input.Split('_');      
    return string.Join("_", parts.Take(parts.Length - 1));
}
```

Or if the date suffix is always the same length, you *could* also just substring:

```
private static string RemoveDateFixedLength(string input)
{
    //Removes last 9 characters (8 for date, 1 for underscore)
    return input.Substring(0, input.Length - 9);
}
```

However I feel like the first approach is better, this is just another option.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DP23ol)

Comment: FYI, I was not the person who downvoted, but my guess on why is that the question was specifically about how to do this using regex and your answer ignored that requirement.  I would not have downvoted for that and I am glad to see you got upvoted.  Also, thanks for the fiddle link.   That's pretty nifty.